# recursion on irregular matrix can't find result

Tags: python, recursion

I wanted to practice recursions a bit and thought that searching in irregular matrices would be fun. I have this simple recursion that works, but somehow doesn't complete the whole array. It can't find numbers 8-11. It needs to return coordinates where the match is so I can work with it later. Am I missing out something?

```py
array = [
    [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, [6, [7, 0]]]], [8, 9], 10, 11]
    ]

def searchArray(array, searched, coordinates=[]):
    for i, dimension in enumerate(array):
        if type(dimension) == int:
            if dimension == searched:
                return coordinates+[i,]
        else:
            coordinates.append(i)
            return searchArray(dimension, searched, coordinates=coordinates)

searched = 5
coordinates = searchArray(array, searched)
print(coordinates)
```

Comment: By the way, there is no point using `np.array` with "irregular matrices."

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems like you are trying to find the "searched" dimension? In the example you provided, the 5th dimension?

Comment: @Meredith Yes, I need the coordinates. I updated the issue a bit and I accepted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return from the function as soon as you make a recursive call on a nested list, whether or not it found `searched`. So the `for` loop never continues looking in the remainder of the list.

You need to check whether the recursion was successful before returning.

Also, you shouldn't modify `coordinates` in place with `append()`. You'll end up returning a list of all the coordinates that you descended into, whether or not it was successful. Pass a new list as the argument in the recursion.

```
def searchArray(array, searched, coordinates=[]):
    for i, dimension in enumerate(array):
        if type(dimension) == int:
            if dimension == searched:
                return coordinates+[i,]
        else:
            found = searchArray(dimension, searched, coordinates=coordinates + [i])
            if found:
                return found
    return None # Not found
```